# Setinterval() function need to reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create section with couple images.Idea is to dynamically change those images, but my problem is: when section is loaded and animation is complete whole process **stop** but it should **continue** **all over again**.

Can somebody help me to achieve that?

Thank you.

Here is my code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 setInterval(function(){

       var $slide = $('div.slideUp');
       $slide.removeClass('slideUp');
       $slide.next().addClass('slideUp');

   },2000);


});
```

```css
.slideSection{
 background: #000;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 25px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 

 }
.block{
 width:  100%;
 float: left;
 display: none;
}

.block img {
    float: left;
 width:  25%;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0;
}

.slideUp{
 display:  block;
 animation: slideUp 1s 1;
 position: relative;
 
}

@keyframes slideUp{
 from{
  opacity:  .0;
  transform: translate(0, 300px);
  
 }
 to{
  opacity:  1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);

 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="slideSection">

<div class="block slideUp ">

        <img src="img/css.png" alt="css">
  <img src="img/js.png" alt="js">
  <img src="img/css.png" alt="css">
  <img src="img/query.png" alt="js">

 </div>

 <div class="block">

        <img src="img/java.png" alt="css">
  <img src="img/sql.png" alt="js">
  <img src="img/js.png" alt="js"> 

 </div>

   <div class="block">

        <img src="img/query.png" alt="js">
        <img src="img/java.png" alt="css"> 

   </div> 

 </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is not infinite because last element do not have `next()` elements. You should check for that to appear and then take first element of collection instead.

Check the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
   setInterval(function(){

       var $slide = $('div.slideUp');
       $slide.removeClass('slideUp');
     
       var $nextSlide = $slide.next();
     
       if(!$nextSlide.length) {
          $nextSlide = $('div.block').eq(0); 
       }  
     
       $nextSlide.addClass('slideUp');

   }, 2000);


});
```

```css
.slideSection{
 background: #000;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 25px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 

 }
.block{
 width:  100%;
 float: left;
 display: none;
}

.block img {
    float: left;
 width:  25%;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0;
}

.slideUp{
 display:  block;
 animation: slideUp 1s 1;
 position: relative;
 
}

@keyframes slideUp{
 from{
  opacity:  .0;
  transform: translate(0, 300px);
  
 }
 to{
  opacity:  1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);

 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="slideSection">

<div class="block slideUp ">

        <img src="img/css.png" alt="css">
  <img src="img/js.png" alt="js">
  <img src="img/css.png" alt="css">
  <img src="img/query.png" alt="js">

 </div>

 <div class="block">

        <img src="img/java.png" alt="css">
  <img src="img/sql.png" alt="js">
  <img src="img/js.png" alt="js"> 

 </div>

   <div class="block">

        <img src="img/query.png" alt="js">
        <img src="img/java.png" alt="css"> 

   </div> 

 </section>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the interval running, but change the way you look for the next slide: check if there is a next one, if so, take it, otherwise pick the first one:

```
  $slide = $slide.next().length ? $slide.next() : $slide.siblings(':first')
  $slide.addClass('slideUp');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help I appreciate that.
Here is the another function that working  properly.

Sincerly

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var currentIndex = 0,
  items = $('.block'),
  itemAmt = items.length;

function cycleItems() {
  var item = $('.block').eq(currentIndex);
  items.removeClass('slideUp');
  item.addClass('slideUp');
}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
}, 2000);
});
```